# php, как реализовать систему сообществ и подписок

Tags: php, yii2

Сижу и ломаю головку над логикой реализации системы подписок на сайте

У меня есть БД user, community

Я хочу сделать чтобы пользователь имел возможность подписаться на сообщество

Для этого создал связную таблицу sub_community, где храню ID пользователя и ID community на какое он подписался

Далее на странице я вывожу полный список community и различные кнопки такие как "подписаться/отписаться"

Значит для вывода данных мне нужно:

1 Получить community(все) (LIMIT 10), далее идет пагинация

2. Получить на что подписан пользователь с таблицы sub_community и проверкой проверять если подписан - отписаться, если не подписан - подписаться
3. Получить количество подписок на сообщество с помощью count

Но если я вывожу на страницу сразу 10 сообществ, у меня делает 10 запросов в БД для получения количества подписок на сообщество

Это уже 13 запросов в БД, как возможно это оптимизировать?

Фреймворк который я использую yii2

Answer (score 0):

Да нет. Почему? Логика-то правильная, Вы только про количество подписок не до конца дописали условие. Надо было просто `group by` добавить.
Что надо:

1. Получить все сообщества.
2. Получить одним запросом количество подписок `SELECT COUNT(id_community), id_community FROM sub_community GROUP BY id_community`. Это вернёт для каждой группы количество подписок на них.
3. Получить подписки пользователя на группы.
4. Пробежаться по полученным массивам, и вывести всё с нужными условиями.

Более конкретно без кода сказать сложно.

Comment: Может подскажете как возможно это было бы реализовать с помощью db design patterns?

Comment: @DenysMak С помощью базы данных? Ну. Даже не знаю, искать надо. Я на php делал. Очень хороший сайт - [refactoring guru](https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/php) Там про все паттерны написано с  примерами и подробно. На нескольких языках. Либо [тут](https://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/README.html) можете почитать